# render two components in react conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

currently working on a simple navbar component. The following is my code:

```
{isLoggedIn ? 
                <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>Logout</Link></Navbar.Brand> 
            : 
                <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/registration" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Register</Link></Navbar.Brand>   
                <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/login" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Login</Link></Navbar.Brand>
}
```

When the user is logged in, I want a logout button to appear, and when they are not logged in I want both register and login buttons to appear. But I cannot do both at the same time when isLoggedIn is false. Any way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: btw I don't recommend you styling your components in your .js, it will soon give headache...

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will make a css instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
{isLoggedIn ? <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>Logout</Link></Navbar.Brand> 
            : <div>
                  <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/registration" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Register</Link></Navbar.Brand>   
                  <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/login" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Login</Link></Navbar.Brand>
              </div>
}
```

**Edit**: as suggested below, it is also possible to wrap between fragments.

Comment: you can also wrap those two buttons in Fragment. like <> .....The two buttons ....</>

Comment: Thank you Mamoon Ahmed! Although the answer did work , it made the styling weird. Your answer did not affect the styling at all, so I used Fragments instead. But Thank you so much tony_merguez.